# Reading JavaScript function statement by statement

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to read a javascript function as a string statement by statement? To make it clearer, if I have this code:

```
var fun = function(str) {
        alert(1);
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(request),
                success: function(myDone) {
                    return function(data) {
                        requestComplete(data, myDone);
                    }
                }
            }
            return str;
        };
```

I want the result to be an array of strings like the following:

```
["alert(1);",
"$.ajax({
type: \'POST\',
url: url,
dataType: \'json\',
data: JSON.stringify(request),
success: function(myDone) {
return function(data) {
requestComplete(data, myDone);
}}}", "return str;"]
```

Comment: You can always just load the ‘.js’ file and read each line. Beyond that what you’re describing is a compiler.

Comment: console.log(fun.toString().split(";"));

Comment: I found a npm package called acorn [link](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn) that is able to tokenize all all javascript statements into neasted objects. I it somehow close to what I need but I am still looking for something closer.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(fun.toString())` will show you the function's code as a string without calling it

`fun.toString().split('\n')` will add each line to a new array item

The only other way I can see is to split with `;`, but you'd need to use `;` at the end of each statement you want to separate instead of the correct syntax